# Vue.js changing all selects with v-for

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm starting with vue.js and I'm looping through some users and listing them inside bootstrap `cols`. The number of `cols` will grow with the number of registered users.

Each `col` has the data from each user and there is a `select` inside each user `col`.

These `select`'s are populated with users posts according to their ID's.

So I have `v-for` inside `v-for`.

`v-for` for posts' `select`  inside the users `v-for`.

My problem is that when I change a `select option` it changes all the `selects` for all other users.

Is there a way to change only the user's `select` that I'm really changing?

html:

```
<div class="row" id="app">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in hosters" v-bind:key="item.id" class="col-md-6 mb-50">
        <h4 class="mb-0">{{ item.name }} {{ item.lastname }}</h4>


        <div class="tour-options-select">
            <select id="select-suggestions" name="tour-options-dropdown" v-model="tour"
                @change="openTour(tour)" class="tour-options-dropdown"
                v-on:mouseover="listTours(item.id)">
                <option v-for="tour in tours" v-bind:value="tour.id">{{ tour.title }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

vue.js

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        city: 'mycity',
        hosters: null,
        tours: null,
        tour: "",
    },
    created: function () {
        this.searchHoster()
    },
    methods: {
        searchHoster: function () {
            axios.post('searchHoster.php', { "city": this.city }).then((response) => {
                this.hosters = response.data;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        },
        listTours: function (id) {
            console.log(id);
            axios.post('resultPageGetTours.php', { "hostID": id }).then((response) => {
                this.tours = response.data;
                console.log(this.tours);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        openTour: function(id){
            console.log(id);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I am unable to see any "_v-for inside v-for._"

Comment: sorry...I reduced the number of `div`s so it stayed outside. I'm going to update it

Comment: Your select's `v-model` is a single `tour` string. If you want each `hoster` to have their own tour, then you need to have separate models. Like a property on each `hoster` or a separate array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my `array` to include tours as a nested array in `response.data`. So I could loop through it in `select v-for`:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in hosters" v-bind:key="item.id" class="col-md-6 mb-50">
    <h4 class="mb-0">{{ item.name }} {{ item.lastname }}</h4>

    <div class="tour-options-select">
        <select id="select-suggestions" name="tour-options-dropdown" class="tour-options-dropdown">
            <option v-for="tour in item.tours">{{ tour.title }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I'm getting all users data into a single response and working based on it.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `v-model="tour"`. Which means all the users share the same `v-model`. You probably want to use a `tours` model property which would hold an array matching your array of users. Or it could be an object, where you use the `user.id` as `key`.

i.e: `v-model="tours[user.id]"`

---

Another option (which probably makes more sense, I wouldn't know without a minimal reproducible example), is to save each tour inside its respective user object and use `v-model="user.tour"`. In which case, if you need all tours, you could use:

```
const allTours = users.map(u => ({id: u.id, tour: u.tour}))
```